# python unittest - with a parameter list generated at runtime

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there a possibility to give a Unit test a parameter, which is provided at runtime?

For example I've connected 5 COM-Ports to my machine. The test environment should select the correct COM-Port and run its test with it. So whats tested is not the actual python code, the python unit test tool is basically used to verify the communication established with by a python script. Depending on initial communication a number of tests with according parameters (e.g. the comport used) should be selected and added to the batch ( test suite ).

In the next step I want to iterate over an array containing COM-Ports and other optiones.

There is a decorator @parametrized. This solution looks nice and invokes the test like desired. But it is not possible, to use this at run time. The decorator is initiated when the script is loaded. The only workaround known to me is to use a global variable to pass the COM-Port to the TestCase. The tests then must be invoked by a test runner.

**To sum up:**

Is there a possibility to parametrize a test at run time?
This then could also be added to a testsuite to have a list of same tests only differ in their parameters.
Or an other alternative would be to assign the parameter in the `setUpClass()` and have anyhow to run several tests again, but with other parameters. Probably this is possible?

**So, how do I set up tests with parameter in python with unit test during runtime?**

Answer (score 0):

Well the only way to find out if the COM port is correct is by communicating with it. What kind of COM port are we talking about? A 3D printer for example will send periodic commands signaling that it is ready for use, you could use this to detect if there is a 3D printer connected. In python you can easily get a list of available COM ports and try to connect to one of them. I once wrote an interface that could connect to any of an automatically generated list of available COM ports. Maybe you can use parts of it to complete your project:

```
import math
import serial
import wx
import threading

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title = "Hydroponics controller")

        self.comport = ""
        self.baudrate = 0
        self.ser = serial.Serial()

        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = Notebook(self)

        tab1 = connectionTab(nb)
        tab2 = ControllerTab(nb)

        nb.AddPage(tab1, "Connection")
        nb.AddPage(tab2, "Controller")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.p.SetSizer(sizer)

class Notebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent.p)
        self.ser = parent.ser

class connectionTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.p = parent

        comLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Serial port", pos = wx.Point(10, 10), size = wx.Size(64, 20))
        self.comList = wx.ListBox(self, size = wx.Size(64, 128), choices = [], pos = wx.Point(10, 40), style = wx.LB_SINGLE)

        baudrateLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Baudrate", pos = wx.Point(84, 10), size = wx.Size(64, 20))
        self.baudrateList = wx.ListBox(self, size = wx.Size(64, 128), choices = ["9600", "115200", "250000"], pos = wx.Point(84, 40), style = wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.baudrateList.SetSelection(1)

        self.refreshButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Refresh", pos = wx.Point(158, 40))
        self.refreshButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.refreshButton_clicked)

        self.connectButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Connect", pos = wx.Point(158, 70))
        self.connectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.connectButton_clicked)

        self.statusLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "", pos = wx.Point(158, 100))

        self.refreshDevices()

    def refreshButton_clicked(self, event):
        self.refreshDevices()

    def connectButton_clicked(self, event):
        try:
            self.p.ser = serial.Serial(self.comList.GetStringSelection(), self.baudrateList.GetStringSelection())
            self.statusLabel.SetLabel("Connection succesful.")
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            self.statusLabel.SetLabel("Connection failed.")

    def refreshDevices(self):
        self.availableDevices = []
        self.comList.Clear()
        for i in range(0,256):
            try:
                tmp = serial.Serial("COM{}".format(i))
                self.comList.Append("COM{}".format(i))
            except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
                continue
        if(self.comList.GetCount()):
            self.comList.SetSelection(0)

class ControllerTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.threadStopped = True
        self.t = threading.Thread(target = self.runSequence)
        self.t.start()

        ROWS = 3
        ROWS_POS = [40, 370, 700]
        COLUMNS = 10
        COLUMNS_POS = [0, 88, 176, 264, 352, 440, 528, 616, 704, 792]

        self.commandList = []
        self.buttonList = []

        for i in range(0, COLUMNS):
            for j in range(0, ROWS):
                self.buttonList.append(PlantButton(self, COLUMNS_POS[i], ROWS_POS[j], wx.Point(i * 110 + 10, j * 30 + 10)))

        self.homeAllButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Home all", pos = wx.Point(10, ROWS * 30 + 10))
        self.homeAllButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.homeAllButton_clicked)

        self.dwellButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Dwell 1s", pos = wx.Point(10, (ROWS + 1) * 30 + 10))
        self.dwellButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.dwellButton_clicked)

        self.commandListBox = wx.ListBox(self, size = wx.Size(192, 512), choices = [], pos = wx.Point(10, (ROWS + 2) * 30 + 10))

        self.startSequenceButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Start sequence", pos = wx.Point(212, (ROWS + 2) * 30 + 10))
        self.startSequenceButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.startSequenceButton_clicked)

        self.saveFileButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Save to file", pos = wx.Point(212, (ROWS + 3) * 30 + 10))
        self.saveFileButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.saveFileButton_clicked)

        self.deleteCommandButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Delete selected command", pos = wx.Point(212, (ROWS + 4) * 30 + 10))
        self.deleteCommandButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.deleteCommandButton_clicked)

    def homeAllButton_clicked(self, event):
        self.commandList.append("G92 X200\nG1 X0 F6000\nG28 XYZ\n")
        self.commandListBox.Append("Home all")

    def dwellButton_clicked(self, event):
        self.commandList.append("G4 P1000\n")
        self.commandListBox.Append("Dwell for 1 second")

    def startSequenceButton_clicked(self, event):
        self.threadStopped = False

    def saveFileButton_clicked(self, event):
        file = open("sequence.gcode", "w")
        for i in range(0, len(self.commandList)):
            file.write(self.commandList[i])
        file.close()

    def deleteCommandButton_clicked(self, event):
        index = self.commandListBox.GetSelection()
        if(index == wx.NOT_FOUND):
            return
        self.commandList.pop(index)
        self.commandListBox.Delete(index)
        if(index == 0):
            self.commandListBox.SetSelection(0)
        else:
            self.commandListBox.SetSelection(index - 1)


    def runSequence(self):
        while True:
            if(self.threadStopped == False):
                sequenceLength = len(self.commandList)
                index = 0

                self.parent.ser.write("G92 X100\nG1 X0 F6000\nM340 P3 S2000\nG28 XYZ\n")

                while((index < sequenceLength) & (self.threadStopped == False)):
                    data = self.parent.ser.readline()
                    if(len(data) != 0):
                        print "READ: {}".format(data),
                    if(data == "ok 0\r\n"):
                        print "SENT: {}".format(self.commandList[index]),
                        self.parent.ser.write(self.commandList[index])
                        index += 1

                print "Stopped"
                self.threadStopped = True

class PlantButton:
    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, buttonPos):
        self.parent = parent
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.buttonPos = buttonPos

        self.button = wx.Button(self.parent, -1, "({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y), pos = self.buttonPos)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self, event):
        self.parent.commandList.append("G1 X{} Y{} F6000\n".format(self.y, self.x))
        self.parent.commandList.append("G1 Z70 F6000\nG4 P1000\nM340 P3 S2500\nG4 P500\nM340 P3 S2468\nG4 P1000\nG91\nG1 X-40 F6000\nG90\nG1 Z0 F6000\n")
        self.parent.commandList.append("G1 X700 F6000\nG4 P1000\nM340 P3 S2000\n")
        self.parent.commandListBox.Append("Go to position ({}, {})\n".format(self.x, self.y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thank you for your answere, but the comport is not the problem, it's just a example for a thing which has to be determined when the script is already envoked. I've tool, which lists me all ports, where my devices are listen. The core of the question is about the unit test in how to archive something like a batch.